# ¿Abrir app Android desde html?

Tags: html, android

Quiero abrir una app instalada en android desde un enlace href de una web HTML.
Lo mismo que abro WhatsApp para enviar un mensaje... pues quiero abrir otra app, pero no lo consigo.

Código para whatsapp:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=TEXTO A ENVIAR">ENVIAR MENSAJE</a>
```

Código para la app:

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=app_name;package=com.app_name;end">ABRIR APP</a>
```

Comment: Tienes que agregar un `<intent-filter>` en el manifest. [Mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3469983/5587982) y/o las otras respuestas de ese hilo.

Answer (score 2):

Para que pueda ser abierta una aplicación al cargar un url, debes definirlo dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, debes definir un [intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) a tu Activity que deseas sea abierta al cargar la url especificada, importante definir la categoría [BROWSABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```

> La actividad de destino permite que la inicie un navegador web para
>   mostrar datos a los que hace referencia un vínculo, como una imagen o
>   un mensaje de correo electrónico.

La url que deseas abra esta Activity de tu aplicación debe ser especificada mediante un `scheme`, que incluso puede ser diferente a https y el `host`, por ejemplo si deseas que la url "https://www.totiskotis.com" abra tu aplicación, esta sería la configuración:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.totiskotis.com" />
            </intent-filter>

  </activity>
```

---

#### Abrir aplicación por medio de su "package name".

> Gracias por la respuesta, pero no tengo acceso al Activity, no es una
>   aplicación mía, sino de un tercero. –

Si deseas abrir una aplicación en la cual no puedes modificar su AndroidManifest.xml puedes usar esta opción en la cual es necesario conocer su "package name".

```
String package_name = "com.package.address";

Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package_name);
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}else{
   //La aplicación no se encuentra instalada en el dispositivo.
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero no tengo acceso al Activity, no es una aplicación mía, sino de un tercero.

Comment: @Juanjo agregué una actualización para darte una opción en el caso que describes, saludos.

Comment: ¿Así? <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

 <script>
  var package_name = "com.package.address";

  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package_name);
  if (launchIntent != null) { 
      startActivity(launchIntent);
  }else{
     //La aplicación no se encuentra instalada en el dispositivo.
  }
 </script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Con este código me abre aplicaciones que vengan de playStore, o incluso abre el playStore si no está instalada. <a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=com.wiseplay;package=com.wiseplay;end">WISEPLAY</a>

Answer (score 0):

Juanjo, lo estoy probando y no lo consigo hacer funcionar.
No se si es algo que me falta emn el index o por permisos.
¿Podrías orientarme o pasarme un ejemplo del index?
Gracias